# Android Google Sign In failed

Tags: android

I am trying to use Google Firebase sdk to Google sign in I have possibilities tried all possible things to solve the issue, But getting one error in firebaseAuthWithGoogle method.

> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)' on a null object reference
>                         at com.aabsys.practice.login.SigninActivity.firebaseAuthWithGoogle(SigninActivity.java:107)
>                         at com.aabsys.practice.login.SigninActivity.onActivityResult(SigninActivity.java:89)

And my Method of here is :

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.d("TAG", "Google sign in failed", e);
            // ...
        }
    }
}



private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {

    Log.d("TAG", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getIdToken());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

    Log.d("TAG", "credentials:" + credential);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    } else {
                        Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SigninActivity.this, "Authentication Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

I am getting data in `acct.getIdToken()` 
Can anybody please help what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you enable google sign in firebase console?

Comment: Yes I have enabled the google signin

Comment: Getting all the details in the task?

Comment: Details as in what ??

Comment: Geeting all the account details, Like mail id and all.

Comment: Looks like you have not initialize your mAuth.